# html/css submenus require variable width

Tags: html, css

I'm am working on menus for a webpage.  As it is now, my submenus are restricted to an 80px width which is defined in the css file under `.dropdown > li {}`.  If I have a lengthy submenu li element like:
`<li><a href="#">Most Popular Artists</a></li>`
 the submenu gets truncated to just "Most".

I need some guidance on how to allow the submenus to display everything they contain. Please advise.

HTML:

```
<nav id="top_menu">
  <img src="media/images/logo_large.jpg">
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropdown_trigger">
      <a href="#">NEWS</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Most Popular Artists</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem2</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem3</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li>
    <li class="dropdown_trigger">       
      <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem2</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem3</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul> 
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#top_menu{
   position: relative;
   top:35px;
   left: 90px;
   width:660px;
   height:55px;
   background-color: black;
   border:1px solid black;
   opacity:0.6;
   filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.dropdown {
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
    padding: 1px 0 0 1px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    line-height: 55px;
    list-style: none;
}

.dropdown a {
    background: black repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;   
    height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
    color: #30B3FF;
    background: #666;
}

.dropdown ul a {
    background: black;
}

.dropdown > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 12px Tahoma; 
    *display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
     /* IE7 hack to make inline-block work right */
    *zoom: 1;
    display: inline;

}

.dropdown li.dropdown_trigger {

    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
}

.dropdown ul {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: -1px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown ul {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown li.dropdown_trigger:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: make the dropdown menu of larger width. Change to `width: 200px;` or anything that suits your purpose or you can use `width:auto;` for variable width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.dropdown a {
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is fixing the height of an item and cutting its contents. You can remove the height (the line-height will suffice), or change it to min-height to be sure. And remove the overflow.

```
.dropdown a {
    min-height: 25px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

If you do that, then all the text will show, and the menu item will be multi-line.

You can then add

```
.dropdown a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

if you don't want the text to wrap. This will cause the menu to become wider.

Comment: The white-space: nowrap; property was what I was missing.  I wasn't aware that existed.  The submenus look fine now. thanks.

Comment: Come to think of it, if you do the other changes as well, and change `nowrap` to `pre-line` or `pre-wrap`, you can force a menu item to break by adding a return/enter in it. That might come in handy if you have a *really* long item that you would want to wrap. On the other hand, you can add a `<br>` in that case as well, if it will ever occur :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the truncation is caused by the overflow: hidden property your using on .dropdown a

```
.dropdown a {
    background: black repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    <!-- overflow: hidden; -->

    height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Try removing that. Also, with that removed you may want to adjust the margins your using to pull the li tag further left. You can also use a negative margin if your li tag is already at zero.

Comment: If you remove that, the text of the top menu item will run over the others. B.t.w. that's not how CSS comments are written. ;-)

Comment: Well, that did help somewhat.  The submenus are still confined to the 80px width and the text appears in full now, but it wraps around within the 80px boundary.  I want the text to be on one line and the boundary to grow to the widest text. Did I describe that right?